# $parent.$index always returns 0

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an `ng-repeat` inside another one and I am trying to find out the parents index.

Because it is being ordered after the fact, I can't do the typical

```
ng-repeat="(step_index, step) in flow"
```

Does anyone know why this would be happening?

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="step in flow | orderBy:'+step_number'">
        <div class="step_container">
            <div class="step_content">
                <div ng-repeat="task in step.tasks">
                    <div class="task_container">
                        <div class="task_content">      
                            {{ $parent.$index }} - {{ $index }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ng-init="$parentIndex = $index"` on your parent `<li>`, then call `$parentIndex` in the child `ng-repeat`

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="step in flow | orderBy:'+step_number'" ng-init="$parentIndex = $index">
        <div class="step_container">
            <div class="step_content">
                <div ng-repeat="task in step.tasks">
                    <div class="task_container">
                        <div class="task_content">      
                            {{ $parentIndex }} - {{ $index }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```